# onBeforeAction: How to Check Email Verified

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to check the email is verified on the router within an onBeforeAction hook but it's throwing 2 errors. Do you know how to address both?

Error 1:

```
Exception in callback of async function: .onBeforeAction@http://localhost:3000/lib/router.js?5f85a874ea86a78deb8c19a394c27e00c5a5f753:34:9
```

Error 2:

```
Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?
```

The code:

```
onBeforeAction: function () {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        if (!user.emails[0].verified) { // line 34
            Router.go('confirmEmail');
        } else if (!user.gamertagScanned) {
            Router.go('confirmGt');
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    } else {
        this.render('aboutUs');
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing a `Router.go()` from within *onBeforeAction* - I suspect you want `this.render('confirmEmail')` and `this.render('confirmGt')` instead.